# Show Next fieldset OnKeyPress Enter - Multi Step Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, fieldset, onkeypress

I am working with Multi Step Form with Progress Bar using jQuery and CSS3
, from this codepen example -
`codepen.io/orozcokapo/pen/LmgjYg`

It is working absolutely fine OnClick mouse events. 
But it is not working on pressing enter key.

Could anybody please tell me,

How can I make it show next fieldset OnKeyPress Enter button?

Comment: Add another event `onkeypress` and check key by testing it using `e.keycode`, for enter button it would be 13

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must bind enter button to make it work

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches
var step=1;

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
  step++;
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
  step--;
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
      if (step == 1) {
        $('.next.action-button').click();
      } else if (step == 2) {
        $('.next.action-button').last().click();
      } else {
        $('.submit.action-button').click();
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have tried given code but its not working.

Comment: Have you tried focusing in the input field before pressing enter?

Comment: Yes tried not working. Can you please post exact method for above code.

Comment: I added listener for enter key in input fields. When you focus on the field, if you press enter key, it will trigger a click to the next buttons and the submit button

Comment: Thanks for Help..Above code worked after some tweaks in HTML. `<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />`  In this line I just changed input type to **submit** and it did the magic  - `<input type="submit" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />`